# Can't select element in drop down menu

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuwG7.png

I am following  the Full Stack .NET Course on Pluralsight and everything has been running fine until now. When I am logged in as a user and trying to add a gig to the database, I am unable to select a genre in the drop down and thus can't add the gig. I can view the genres just fine, I just can't select one.

Here is the code for the drop-down in the Create View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Genre)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Genre, new SelectList(Model.Genres, "Id", "Name"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Genre)
</div>
```

This is my Gig class in the viewmodels folder:

```
public class GigFormViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Venue { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [FutureDate]
    public string Date { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ValidTime]
    public string Time { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public byte Genre { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public IEnumerable<Genre> Genres { get; set; }

    public DateTime GetDateTime()
    {
        return DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0} {1}", Date, Time));
    }
}
```

And this is the code for the HttpPost action in the controller:

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(GigFormViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            viewModel.Genres = _context.Genres.ToList();
            return View("Create", viewModel);
        }
        var gig = new Gig()
        {
            ArtistId = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
            DateTime = viewModel.GetDateTime(),
            GenreId = viewModel.Genre,
            Venue = viewModel.Venue
        };
        _context.Gigs.Add(gig);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

I can't figure out why I am not able to select a genre and save it to the database. It does not give me a validation error when i click "Save", but instead reloads the page. Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't mark `Genres` as `Required` on the ViewModel since this is just a supporting list you need when displaying the view. But when the form in the view is submitted, this property will have no value, so that the validation fails.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to save a gig now, but I am still unable to let the genre selected in the drop-down stay selected when i click it. I will still mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @user1696992 Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384865/html-dropdownlistfor-always-displays-blank-even-with-a-list-item-selected - Maybe you have the same issue with the CSS?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is you marked required in `Genres`

```
  [Required]
  public IEnumerable<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
```

in dropdownlist

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Genre, new SelectList(Model.Genres, "Id", "Name"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

`m.Genre` will return the selected value which should be set as `required` but `new SelectList(Model.Genres, "Id", "Name")` does only one trip to populate the data it does not return the data back to modal